# Larva attacking frog ? Guide about this

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, herpetology

[image]

The above picture was taken in western forest of India where a larva attached itself to a frog neck. What is it and how it will effect the frog?

Comment: Maybe an Epomis larva? Just based on the fact that it's attacking a frog. It is not supposed to exist in India, but it does range as far east as Tajikistan, so maybe it's plausible.

Comment: Actually it seems there have been [two records of Epomis in India](https://punemirror.indiatimes.com/pune/others/bug-proves-fatal-for-amboli-amphibians/articleshow/60874517.cms).